# HTML5 and Android: image with transparent background

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, createjs

I have many problems with HTML 5 for mobile.

See photo (same photo) when I'm running on an Android tablet HTML and side as compared running in a browser on mac.

http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/562/brdr.png
Note that black and white lines appear in the image into the Android Tablet.

I'm using the library CreateJS to generate images. In the image the only thing I do is to change x, y, scaleX and scaleY.

PS: The images are in PNG transparent.

Comment: Are you sure this is not cause of image borders?

Comment: @Vikram_Tiwari Sure is not. Double-checked the file. And it works perfect with iOS and desktop.